# How do I convert a delimited list to a multicolumn table in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a list like this:

```
Friut;Taste;Color;Other;Apple;Good;Red and Blue;1;Orange;Really Good;Orange;12
```

And I want to convert it by selecting every 4 delimitations and turning them into rows like this:

```
Fruit    Taste     Color     Other
Apple    Good      Red and G.1
Orange   Really Go.Orange    12
```

How is this possible with Libreoffice (preferred), Openoffice, or Excel?

Edit: The above is an example. I am using it to select 4 delimitations, but there are about 500 rows that I need this to work on.

Edit2: Provided my own (correct) answer

Comment: It would be easier to do this with something like Perl or sed . `echo "Your string" | perl -pe 's/([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*);?/$1,$2,$3,$4\n/g'` and import the result as CSV. Do you really need a solution that uses LO/OO/Excel and nothing more?

Comment: The way you have it listen now, each fruit is a row, as far as character delimited files go...

Comment: I don't really know Perl, and that that looks like a regex string, which I also don't know. This is really cool, I will try this on my document. Is there a way to make this also work with newline?

Comment: Please explain "make this also work with newline". Update your question with an example.

Also, you should learn Perl and regexes, they are very helpful in dealing with text.

Comment: I just meant with a new line, but it doesn't matter. How do I do this with sed? I am trying to run: `sed -e 's/([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*);?/$1,$2,$3,$4\n/g' file.txt`, but it's not working (it's just returning the contents of the file)

Comment: Try `sed -re 's/([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*);?/\1,\2,\3,\4\n/g' file.txt`. That `-r` is important, and `$1, $2,...` are `\1, \2,...` in sed syntax.

Comment: This would also be trivial to do in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer came from user49740:

```
sed -re 's/([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*);?/\1,\2,\3,\4\n/g' input.txt > output.txt
```

The first half of the string:

```
([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*);?
```

Finds 4 groups of `([^;]*)` (all characters before the semicolon) then a semicolon. The second half:

```
\1,\2,\3,\4\n
```

Changes the text to CSV format. `> output.txt` will write the converted file to output.txt.

Answer (score 1):

### VBA macro to split entire rows to multiple rows

[image]

With this macro you split entire rows to multiple rows. You can choose how many columns your want after splitting. just change the value for `iSplit` at the first line. I don't use a specific delimiter, just column counts.

I commented every step. It's easy to adjust the macro to your personal needs.

1. Open Excel and VBA editor with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
2. On the left pane, paste the code under the *sheet* where your data is placed
3. Modify the first two lines according to your needs
4. Execute the macro with <kbd>F5</kbd>

---

```
Const iSplit = 4    '## how many columns do you want after splitting
    
Sub transposeColumn()
    '## search the last row to know how many rows we have to iterate through
    iLastRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    
    '## begin to loop through every row. Begin at last row and go upwards
    For r = iLastRow To 1 Step -1

        '## search the last column in the current row
        iLastCol = Rows(r).Find("*", Cells(r, 1), , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
    
        '## calculate how many new rows we need to insert for this row
        iNewRows = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(iLastCol / iSplit, 0) - 1
        
        '## begin to copy and insert new rows, one by one
        For c = 1 To iNewRows
    
            '## insert a new blank line where we can copy values to
            Rows(r + c).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            
            '## set the source range for easier access later
            Set rngSrc = Range(Cells(r, iSplit * c + 1), Cells(r, iSplit * c + iSplit))
            
            '## copy and paste the range
            rngSrc.Copy Destination:=Cells(r + c, 1)
    
            '## clear all cells which we have just copied
            rngSrc.Clear
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list is a text file, you can use the [Text Import Wizard](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-data-using-the-text-import-wizard-HP010342954.aspx) in Excel. I assume there is a similar tool in both LibreOffice and Openoffice.org.

However, since the delimiters are the `;` signs, when you import there will be a need to arrange the data as it will be imported as a row of values.
You can alter the original text file and add another delimiter that signifies the next row.

Comment: I think stonewareslord is looking for an automated method, i.e. one that does not require manual arrangement of data.

Comment: He didn't **explicitly** declare that he wants a 100% automated way, he said he wanted to use LO/OO/Excel. Unless he uses Macros (and that is only part of Excel AFAIK), other than replacing 2 characters, I don't recall another option. If he did want a script in Perl, Python, etc, then this question would be better suited for SO.

Comment: Well, the above is just an example. I need to run this on a document with about 500 rows in it, so manual is close to impossible.